# How to query a field divided by multiple tags in InfluxDB

Tags: sql-like, influxdb

Our measurement structure looks like this:
**timeStamp** - **sensor**(tag) - **value**(field).

To query the values of more than one tag, the documentation provides the following:
`SELECT value FROM measurement WHERE sensor=sensor_1 OR sensor=sensor_2 OR ...`
Which results a **single column** of values.

But **how to divide the result values by the different sensors(tags) in multiple columns**, maybe something like this: 
`SELECT value.sensor_1, value.sensor_2 FROM measurement` ideally this should be applicable with influxdb-java.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use SELECT, but GROUP BY clause:

```
GROUP BY sensor
```

The result will be row per sensor.

Doc: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.6/query_language/data_exploration/#the-group-by-clause

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can you query data without SELECT clause? When querying over influxdbs HTTP API it expects one of the following keywords first: SELECT, DELETE, SHOW, CREATE, DROP, EXPLAIN, GRANT, REVOKE, ALTER, SET, KILL. Also, the goal is to get one column per sensor not grouping rows by the different sensors. Did i missed something essential?

Comment: That is not a full query - only GROUP BY part. No column per sensor is IMHO impossible. Row per sensor is a standard - you have a (java) code where you can transform it later.

Comment: Okay ... so it comes to expensive string building, I was hoping to resolve this by a more general or efficient way.